# django : showing the same view again and again though the html is changed

Tags: html, django, templates

I have a simple index.html file which have the code like following:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fruktur' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    background-color: #022e3a;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#header {
    font-family: 'Fruktur', cursive;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #065e76;
}
</style>
<head>
<body class="container">
<div id="header">
<p>DaamJani.com</p>
</div>
<div>
<form method="GET">
    Ask for price(e.g.Onion)
<input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
<br/>
<div>No. of elements : {{ prices|length }}</div>
<div>
<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td><td>Price</td><td>Per Amount</td><td>Where</td>
        </tr>
        {% for price in prices %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{price.name}}</td><td>{{price.price}}</td><td>{{price.quantity}}</td><td>{{price.source}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}


</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Though I have added this line recently: `<div>No. of elements : {{ prices|length }}</div>` the app doesn't seem to change once I run the server. I tried clearing the cache and reloading it.
I tried removing the entire div containing the table but it shows the same view as before.
What's wrong with this?

Comment: try to remove your cache for the mean time and run the app. I'm also experience this using cache so I decide to remove my cache and never use it again. But in your problem, just remove it for the mean time and back it later (cache)

Comment: Don't get your answer,sorry. What does it mean for removing it for mean time? And I removed the cache twice! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean disable your cache function not just clearing it. There is no effect if you just only clearing it.

Comment: I don't know how to disable it :( can you please....

Comment: How can I?? I'm not there and I don't know what's the pattern of your codes. Just trace where you put it.

Comment: I didn't put cache anywhere....I just want to disable internal cache support.

Comment: Seems like you are a django expert :) Can I have your gchat or fb id or at least your mail,so that I can knock you sometimes,if you dont mind?Actually I have just started django and it seems quite complicated to me.

Comment: I'm not, I just love programming, my passion... Here is my gmail: catherinetenajeros@gmail.com

Comment: It would be nice of you guys to add the answer below once you've found the solution to the problem. Don't keep it private :P